# How can i make a list menu "collapsible"?

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, menu, collapsable

i have a menu with 4 main items and each one having 3 to 5 sub items.

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a>Diagonóstico</a>

    </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_di1"> › Grátis (na compra de qualquer serviço) </a>

    </li>
    <li><a>Hardware</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub_ha1"> › Instalação/Configuração de Componentes</a>
```

Please check the **[full code](http://jsfiddle.net/fDYMz/2)**.

As you can see in the jsFiddle, all menu items, when clicked show some text in another div.
I put that there just in case it was be needed for further javascript help.
What i want is to have all .sub menus collapsed and when i **mouseover** one of the main ones, it expands the corresponding .sub items so user can see.
Thanks!

EDIT:

I managed to get a nice tutorial in one of the comments and came up with **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/fDYMz/2)**!

What i need now is a way to show ALL the .sub menus from the corresponding .main menus instead of only the first ones.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBh_lMO_SDM
check this out!

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a javascript solution? You can accomplish this with CSS and some adjustment to your HTML if you like.

Comment: @dentaku i managed to get a nice script to work from the video above, i just need a bit tweak and i'll be good to go. (:

Comment: @auicsc I used that tutorial and came up with something really neat, altho still need some tweaks.

Comment: @BrunoCharters Glad to hear it. If you're ever interested in a straight CSS solution, look into the :hover psuedo-class. :)

Comment: you don't have to bind so many click handlers to `.sub_*` elements.

Comment: @Ejay thos don't relate to the menu collapsing at all. except you're there's a way to handle the .sub_* clicks with fewer handlers if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using only HTML and CSS.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="SOME_LINK">Some menu without sub-menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="SOME_LINK2">Some menu without sub-menu 2 </a></li>
    <li>Some menu WITH sub-menu
        <ul>
            <li><a href="SOME_LINK">Some sub-menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="SOME_LINK">Some sub-menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="SOME_LINK3">Some menu without sub-menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul>li>ul{display:none}
ul>li:hover>ul, ul>li:selected>ul{display:block}
```

JS (jQuery) to OPEN all submenus

```
$('#menu li>ul').parent().addClass('selected');
```

JS without Jquery

```
var menus = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('li') 
for(var row in menus){
     if(typeof menus[row] == 'object' && menus[row].getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0){
         menus[row].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].className = 'selected';
     }
}
```

Comment: that'd be the correct solution sir. thanks. i'm marking as correct altho, if you know what i could do to tweak my js into showing ALL submenus. tell me.

Comment: i couldn't get that to work . weirdly . i all looks right tho . can you make me a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to the one mentioned in the question edit, but an already open list item does not re-open when beging clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/g5oc0uoq/

```
$('.content').hide();
$('.listelement').on('click', function(){
  if(!($(this).children('.content').is(':visible'))){
    $('.content').slideUp();
    $(this).children('.content').slideDown();
  } else {
    $('.content').slideUp();
  }
});
```

show() and hide() can be used instead of slideUp() and slideDown() if you have performance issues.